# Login using Facebook, Google, Yahoo and hotmail in Coldfusion Application

Tags: facebook, authentication, coldfusion

I am pretty new to coldfusion. Can some one please guide me how to create a login using Facebook, Google, Yahoo and hotmail. If some can point out to any tutorials availbale online. That would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In 20 mins: Online #ColdFusion Meetup, 12p (US ET), "Auth. made easy using Twitter/Facebook/more", B. Cravens http://t.co/QBHXWWOj

Comment: You really should check out the presentation in my comment above, it starts in 3 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the link. I will definitely attend that. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: http://www.meetup.com/coldfusionmeetup/events/76345002/ is a recording of the meetup.  Also you may check out http://oauth.riaforge.org/  I will warn you, I have been doing programming and ColdFusion for over 13 years, I find Oauth very difficult to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 2):

I'd give this a shot for Facebook:

http://facebooksdk.riaforge.org/

And I would say once you got that working, you'd know quite a bit more about authentication services, and might be able to carve out the others on your own.

Here's one for Google:

http://cfgoogle.riaforge.org/

I don't know of anything good for yahoo or hotmail.